# ASP.NET : get page source into a string

Tags: asp.net

Using ASP.NET, how could I get the page source into a string?

I'm getting the error:

> BC30002: Type 'WebRequest' not defined

Thanks for any help.

My code

```
<html>
<head><title>Get HTML Page Source</title></head>
<body>

<center>Page Source Display<br><br></center>

<%
    DIM strUrl, websitesource, strHtml

    Response.Write("Page Source Display<br>")

    strUrl = "http://www.jb.com.br"
    Response.Write(strUrl)

    Dim myReq As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(strUrl)
    Dim myWebResponse As WebResponse = myReq.GetResponse()
    Dim dataStream As Stream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream,  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to reference (and Import) the `System.Net` assembly to use the `WebRequest` class.

Comment: Are you sure this is ASP.NET? Or is this classic ASP?

Comment: It's classic ASP.

Comment: How to reference and import System.Net?